# Storing History in a Database

Tags: database, database-design, history, relational-database

In regards to storing history within a database, is it better to use a DateEnd (Ex. 1) or a Duration (Ex. 2)?

Or please feel free to even suggest another approach that would be the most effective.

Are there other changes that I should make to one of these Examples if one proves to be the correct approach?  DB being used is MySQL although I don't think it has a bearing on the approach here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two perspectives on this one - firstly, what's the business domain? In your example, you've used "subscription" - these are often sold as "monthly", "weekly", etc. All other things being equal, I prefer my database to align to business concepts when possible. You might even go so far as to create a "subscription_type" table, and derive the duration of the description from the type.

That often clashes with the need for your database to perform. From that point of view, I'd work out what the most common queries are going to be, and see if you can make your database design work with the minimal amount of type conversion or calculation possible. Finding all records where the subscription expires on a given date, for instance, is a lot easier (and probably faster) if you can ask for dateEnd < targetDate, rather than calculating the date by adding the duration to the start date.

Comment: now you got me thinking a bit more.  I will have to look into things and see if the SubscriptionType table could fulfill my needs. "That often clashes with the need for your database to perform" is that in response to your first paragraph and therefore maybe I should just stay away from doing that?  The importance here is to track end dates to let users know when they need to re-up.  Something like 30 day(any increment/s) notices and keep track of expired accounts for access restriction. Of course other internal quires would be done but with that same basic concept in mind.

Comment: Yes, the performance concern does often conflict with the desire to model the business domain. In your case, I wouldn't consider that a major issue unless you have millions of subscribers. If you want to create reminders etc., I'd consider putting them into a "reminders" table, with a status to track whether they have been acted on -that way, you can keep track and even out the reminders if necessary, or send them out on days when people are more likely to respond (weekends may be worse than weekdays).

Answer (score 1):

If you have start date and end date, you can always (or should always be able to) compute duration.  If you have start date and duration, you can always (or should always be able to) compute end date.

You can also record all three and enforce a row constraint to the effect that they cannot "mismatch".

However, one very frequent kind of usage of the "end date" datum, is to filter out rows that are "not current" : something like WHERE END_DATE > CURRENTSYSTEMDATE().  If you have that kind of usage, then it is probably not advisable to "leave out" the end date.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the end date as opposed to the duration. You can calculate the duration when needed. Seems to make more sense storing measurement points instead of measurements.

Comment: If you use duration, you are actually losing information - it is always possible to go from measurement points to measurements, but most often impossible to recreate the measurement points from the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Derived values such as duration don't need to be stored in the database.

Your approach to capture history of a row will work in some cases, but to truly catch all changes to all rows you will likely need another table, something like subscription_hist that will be updated by a trigger on insert and update of the subscription.  Then you would have to keep track only of last_modified_date and last_person_changed_by.  Everything else could be derived.  This way you could see what happened to the row over time.  I don't have any pictures to clarify, but this method, if implemented carefully would allow for full point-in-time recovery of data, as well as maintaining historical information.

Comment: When you introduce another such as subscription_hist that you mention are you not just creating duplication within the database?  Or are you suggesting something as a transaction table in a financial system?